# ASP.NET Membership passwordStrengthRegularExpression and GeneratePassword

Tags: .net, asp.net, security, membership

The generatePassword method in the asp.net membership provider allows only length and alphanumeric characters to be set.

However there is also the property passwordStrengthRegularExpression

Does GeneratePassword makes use of the property above. It would be great if it did but I assume it dosn't?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, unfortunately it doesn't.  Please see [`GeneratePassword`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membership.generatepassword.aspx):

> The random password created by the
>   GeneratePassword method is not
>   guaranteed to pass the regular
>   expression in the
>   PasswordStrengthRegularExpression
>   property. However, the random password
>   will meet the criteria established by
>   the MinRequiredPasswordLength property
>   and the
>   numberOfNonAlphanumericCharacters
>   parameter.

Comment: @Andrew Hare - Do you know if there is a way to generate a new password that will conform to the Regex criteria? I guess I could use `GeneratePassword` and test the output against my Regex and keep looping until I get a match. This feels clunky though...

Comment: @AlexP did you find an alternative solution to this?

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue and took the following approach;

```
newRndPwd = String.Empty;

do 
{
    newRndPwd = Membership.GeneratePassword(MinRequiredPasswordLength, MinRequiredNonAlphanumericCharacters)
}
while(!Regex.IsMatch(newRndPwd, PasswordStrengthRegularExpression)
```

Comment: don't you think this is too risky?

Comment: @akd did you find a better solution for this by any chance?